# A regular expression that has a even number of a's and that does not contain the pattern aba

Tags: logic, regular-expressions

The problem I have is that for the language {a, b} I have to provide a regular expression that has an even number of a's and that does not contain the pattern aba.

I know that for an even number of a's the regular expression is

```
b*(ab*ab*)*
```

But I don't know how to make sure there is no pattern aba and how to combine the two.

Comment: The only things allowed between two a's are other a's or multiple b's. Can you write a regular expression which only matches multiple b's?

Comment: @mephistolotl I have been trying and I got this `b*((bb)*a(a+(bb)*a))*b*` is this correct?

Comment: Well...does it match `babbba`?

Comment: @FlubberBeer If you're allowed to use the `+` syntax, I think it would be more useful after a `b`.